# How to cancel mouse click default behavior?

Tags: javascript, events, mouseevent

How can I cancel mouse events in JavaScript?

When I left-click on any object I want to cancel the default behavior of the left mouse click.
Is it posible in JavaScript?

On google map on left mouse drag map pan to any direction.

google.maps.event.addListener(Layers.map, 'mousemove', function (event) {
  // what to do heve
 }

Comment: please be more specific. what do you mean by 'default behaviour'? please give a concrete code example.

Comment: Actually @Kaii I think 'default behavior' is specific enough - it's left to the browser to implement what that behavior is (though its all the same), and Javascript disables this with the `preventDefault()` method, which is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: google.maps.event.addListener(Layers.map, 'mousemove', function (event) { // what to do heve }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, true);
```

whatever "default behavior" is in your case...

Comment: Code ofter  e.preventDefault(); not execute , i neet to perform that cancel event default behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the context menu by using the oncontextmenu event handler in the body tag of your page